# jQgrid shows 1 of N in the pager when there is no data [Form Editing local Data]

Tags: jqgrid

I still have the issue where the pager still shows 1 of NaN inspite of the fact that I have downloaded after selecting the grid.formedit.js. Below the comment containing the list of modules added to jquery.jqGrid.min.js.

```
Blockquote
```

/* * jqGrid 3.8.2 - jQuery Grid * Copyright (c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses * Date:2010-12-14 * Modules: grid.base.js; jquery.fmatter.js; grid.custom.js; grid.common.js; grid.formedit.js; jquery.searchFilter.js; grid.inlinedit.js; grid.celledit.js; jqModal.js; jqDnR.js; grid.subgrid.js; grid.grouping.js; grid.treegrid.js; grid.import.js; JsonXml.js; grid.setcolumns.js; grid.postext.js; grid.tbltogrid.js; grid.jqueryui.js; */

```
Blockquote
```

However, in my case it is when editing the data manually.

The script is as follows:

```
$('#list').jqGrid(
{ 
datatype: "xmlstring", 
datastr: urlParams,
colNames:[
      'Parameter Name',
      'Parameter Value'
      ], 
colModel:[ {name:'pName',index:'pName', width:100,editable:true,editoptions:  {size:25}}, 
       {name:'pValue',index:'pValue',width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}} 
     ], 
rowNum:10, 
rowList:[10,20,30], 
pager: '#pager', 
sortname: 'pName', 
viewrecords: true, 
sortorder: "desc", 
caption:"URL Parameters", 
editurl:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GenerateXMLResponse.do", //dummy URL
height:210 ,
width:420

} ).navGrid('#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
```

The datastr is initialized to an empty xml string as follows:

```
var defURLParams="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><urlParams/>";

var urlParams =defURLParams;
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can solve the problem including `total` in your data. It is not clear in which form you plan include the data in the XML string used in `datastr`. You should use `xmlReader` to describe the data (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#xml_string) for more details). The definition could be `xmlReader: {root: "urlParams", ...}` (to write more one need know the format of your input data).